# cannot open up port using iptables to use rstudio server

Tags: linux, server, port, rstudio, iptables

I am currently trying to open port 8787 for rstudio server. I have set this up on an ubuntu host, and want to point my browser at the ip address of the ubuntu host, using port 8787 to direct it to rstudio. I can do this from the host machine, but no such luck using a different computer.

When I do

```
netstat - peantl | grep ":8787"
```

I get nothing returned, unlike when checking port 22 which is confirmed as listening. I can there ssh from external machines into the ubuntu host.

So I tried to open up port 8787 with iptables:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8787 -j ACCEPT
```

command runs fine, but then re-checking with netstat I still do not get any output (I was expecting similar output to port 22 as mentioned previously)

I also allowed port 8787 on ufw:

```
sudo ufw allow 8787
```

using `gufw` it confirms port 8787 is open.

What could be the issue? If my network has restricted port 8787 how can I tell? Am I allowing port 8787 correctly with iptables?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

All your `iptables` and `ufw` commands are doing is opening ports in the firewall itself. The fact that there is no output from the `netstat|grep` line means that the `rstudio` software does not actually have the port open for anyone to connect to. This is the issue you need to fix first.